# Acumatica Redirect to a Dashboard and pass parameter value issue

Tags: acumatica

I'm successfully redirecting to a Dashboard passing parameter from Customers screen (AR303000) but, not able to replicate the result when I redirect to the Dashboard from Customer Pop Up Panel. it call the Dashboard without the parameter. I can see the code passing the value correctly, but the Dashboard does not display any value.
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.
Alfredo

Here is a copy of the code.

```
    #region CustomerCard
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.Customer> customerCard;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Card")]
    protected void CustomerCard()
    {
        Customer customer = Base.BAccount.Current; 
        if (customer != null)
        {
            string screenID = "DBPS0007"; //DashboardID 

            PXSiteMapNode sm = GIScreenHelper.GetSiteMapNode(screenID);
            PXGraph graph = GIScreenHelper.InstantiateGraph(screenID);

            if (graph is LayoutMaint)
            {
                LayoutMaint copygraph = graph as LayoutMaint;
                Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new 
                Dictionary<string, object>();

                parameters["CustomerAccountID"] = customer.AcctCD;
                copygraph.Filter.Current.Values = parameters;

                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(sm.Url, copygraph, 
                PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: possibly provide a working  code sample in your question that someone can troubleshoot with?

Comment: Here is a copy of the code.

Comment: Update with Acumatica response: 
This is a know issue and they already have a ticket on this.

Comment: thanks for the update - I would answer your own question based on your comment to close out the question (so it does not remain open forever)